# Web API scaffolding + MVC view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, scaffolding

Visual Studio offers 2 useful scaffolding templates:

- "MVC 5 controller with views, using EntityFramework"
- "Web API 2 controller with actions, using EntityFramework"

Unfortunately, no one of them is exactly what i want.

I need for a "Web API 2 controller with MVC VIEWS, using EntityFramework".

It would be a sort of "merge" between the existing two.

I know it's possible to use a manually created Web API controller on a scaffolded MVC view (see also http://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/using-razor-together-with-asp-net-web-api), but this technique would need for some manual work (a thing that I want to avoid, since I must scaffold hundreds of entities, and my manual work would be massive).

Is there a custom scaffolding template that creates a Web API controller and a MVC view using EntityFramework ?

Comment: If you're trying to return HTML from a WebAPI, you're doing things wrong. That's why there's no tooling for that out of the box.

Comment: I understand what you mean, and I (partially) agree. The fact is I have some technological and project constraints that force me to implement Web API controllers for the entities.
I just want to avoid having 2 controllers (one WebAPI and one MVC) for the same entity. Since using the linked solution seems to solve the problem, I was hoping it could be supported/implemented by a template.

Comment: I don't know if this is possible at all, but maybe you could create a MediaFormatter that uses the view engine from MVC to generate the html view in the case where the client asks for an html view. Just an idea... :)

Comment: _I just want to avoid having 2 controllers (one WebAPI and one MVC) for the same entity._ : Bear in mind that aside of the obvious differences, there are lots of under-the-hood features that come for free with ApiController / Controller and using one to do the job of the other will force you to implement the missing / adapt the inadequate features by hand... I would avoid, and use the right tools for the job.

Comment: Thankyou all for the feedback.
I deeply understand both the two technologies (I use them since their very beginning), so I can agree with your evaluations.
As I said, I want to avoid having 2 classes that - logically speaking -  execute the same CRUD operations in different ways.
Since Web API is (roughly speaking) a model-oriented technology, and MVC is a (again roughly speaking) view-oriented technology, I was hoping to find a good compromise between them, avoiding business  logic duplication.

Answer (score 1):

In an ASP.NET MVC 5 application, which includes Web API 2, you can't have a controller that does both.  You can use an MVC Controller to return web service data, but it is with the overhead of MVC.  In ASP.NET Core, there is only 1 controller, and it is used for both MVC and Web API actions.